# VB.NET Checking for existing files and assigning new Version Numbers to the name?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, version-control, save, filenames

Alright, this one has been driving me up a wall for the past few hours, and I feel like I can almost taste victory, but I am stuck.

I am writing files into a directory based on user supplied requirements, and this particular section deals with assigning a new `Version Number` to the new file. So basically, this creates the new file using a naming convention of:

```
Path\FileName_ver1
Path\FileName_ver2
```

And so on. The issue is, I cannot figure out how to determine if a file with similiar naming (minus the `_ver#` string) exists in the directory, and then parse the name to find out the current version number, and then create the new file using the version number and adding 1 to it.

If you look at my current code, the issue at the moment is arising when it goes into the loop, telling me that the array is out of bounds, even though the file does exist within the directory.

```
Dim strPossibleFilename() As String = Directory.GetFiles(savePath, saveName & "_ver*" & saveExt)
                Dim intVersionNumber As Integer = 1
                For i = 0 To strPossibleFilename.Length - 1
                    If File.Exists(strPossibleFilename(i)) Then
                        Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(strPossibleFilename(i))
                        Dim fullName As String
                        Dim strVersionNumber As String
                        fullName = fileInfo.FullName

                        Dim versionPosition As Integer = fullName.IndexOf("_ver")
                        Dim dotPosition As Integer = fullName.IndexOf(".")
                        Dim versionCharacterCount As Integer = dotPosition - versionPosition
                        strVersionNumber = fullName.Substring(versionPosition, versionCharacterCount)

                        If intVersionNumber < strVersionNumber Then
                            intVersionNumber = strVersionNumber
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i

                If intVersionNumber > 1 Then
                    saveLocation = savePath & saveName & "_ver" & intVersionNumber + 1 & saveExt
                    fstr = New FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                    fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead)
                Else
                    saveLocation = savePath & saveName & "_ver1" & saveExt
                    fstr = New FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                    fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead)
                End If
```

P.S. All of the other functionality works, as far as the writing and everything, I am doing this in multiple places in my code, including assigning other varied strings to file names when one already exists...
Please let me know if you need more information.

**EDIT:**
Made a couple changes based on the answers given, and now it is finding the file, but this brings up a new problem... So I cannot figure out how to ONLY grab the number that is AFTER "_ver" to assign that to intVersionNumber.. Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**
Okay, to solve that issue, I added:

```
Dim strVersionString As String
```

And added a few other things, so now the for loop looks like this:

```
For i = 0 To strPossibleFilename.Length - 1
                    If File.Exists(strPossibleFilename(i)) Then
                        Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(strPossibleFilename(i))
                        Dim fullName As String
                        Dim strVersionString As String
                        Dim strVersionNumber As String
                        fullName = fileInfo.FullName

                        Dim versionPosition As Integer = fullName.IndexOf("_ver")
                        Dim dotPosition As Integer = fullName.IndexOf(".")
                        Dim versionCharacterCount As Integer = dotPosition - versionPosition
                        strVersionString = fullName.Substring(versionPosition, versionCharacterCount)
                        Dim rPosition As Integer = strVersionString.IndexOf("r") + 1

                        strVersionNumber = strVersionString.Substring(rPosition, strVersionString.Length - rPosition)

                        If intVersionNumber < strVersionNumber Then
                            intVersionNumber = strVersionNumber
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i
```

And now it is working :D Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Your wildcard is wrong, it should be "Filename_ver*".  Your For-loop is wrong, it is off by one.  That should be `To strPossibleFilename.Length - 1`.  Computers start counting at 0, not 1.

Comment: AH... thought it would be something along those lines... I fixed the strPossibleFilename.Length - 1 part, but forgot about the filename part....... THANKS!

Comment: That helped, but now I have a new issue that I can finally work on...see my edit^

Comment: Is it important to have the file end if a Version number.  You can get a unique version by concatenating a time stamp to the end. FileName_20130531_142246

Comment: I already have a datetime stamp as one of the possible version logics, we actually have three different ones, version number being one of them. Either way, see my 2nd edit, got it working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, I have a sneaking suspicion here with this line

```
For i = 0 To strPossibleFilename.Length
```

change it to

```
For i = 0 To strPossibleFilename.Length -1
```

and then unless you kissed BillGates daughter and he's pissed off, it should work!

Comment: Ah man, I was really hoping you were right. So, you kinda were... that helped me get through the array, to an extent, problem is, it returned false on the file.exists function, so it skipped down to the else statement and attempted to write a new file, which of course, couldn't happen since it already exists. The exception even says "This file already exists"..

Comment: That helped, but now I have a new issue that I can finally work on...see my edit^

Comment: Super...so bill gates isn't pissed... but I don't understand. you have the `strVersionNumber = fullName.Substring(versionPosition, versionCharacterCount)` isn't that what you want? you already have the version number

Comment: Yes, BUT, for some reason, it starts adding characters to the string starting at the first underscore in "_ver", so the output of the substring is: "_ver1" and of course, you cannot set an integer equal to a string that has letters, only numbers. Do you understand my issue? lol, maybe I should then parse that string itself, search for just the number? Actually... yeah I think I will do that.

Comment: how about `strVersionNumber = fullName.Substring( fullName.indexof("ver")+3, fullName.Length)` so that it starts counting characters AFTER ver.. I don't have vb on this pc, and a 4 instead of 3 might work , but i think you get the idea. or yes parsing is good too

Comment: Yeah, you know I thought of that after I wrote the code I have in the second edit... basically what I added does the same thing, just a little bit harder. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cool! The rest of this sentence is to fill up the minimum required length :P

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, how to get the number after the `_ver`

```
' consider padding the version number
' with leading zeros
' and using a second underscore
' to make it easier to parse for number
Dim fileName As String = "filename_ver_001"
Dim parts As String() = fileName.Split("_"c)
Dim verNumber As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(2))
```

If you add a second underscore, you can use the String.Split to break the filename into an array.

FWIW, if you want a more sortable file list pad out the number with leading zeros. Otherwise filename_ver11 is ordered before filename_ver2

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, I went a different direction, but I appreciate your insight!